# how to getTemplate of a block in my template.phtml in magento2?

Tags: magento2, template

In magento2 I want to get the newsletter template or static block in my `template.phtml`.

I tried to use

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe")->getTemplate('subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

but without success. Can anyone help?

Comment: trying using setTemplate instead of getTemplate method

Comment: i tried it, but not lucky.

Comment: Where is the phtml file exactly located which you would like to set to the block ?

Comment: i create custom file name is my-template.phtml in admin. so i want get newsletter template in my-template.phtml.

Comment: Regarding the answers below, please use `->createBlock(Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe::class)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The `$this` was right for Magento 1, however it is not for Magento 2.

Instead you should use `$block`.

On top of that you should set the template instead of getting it and then call the `toHtml` method that renders the block.

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe")->setTemplate('Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: it not show subscribe. i'm checked in system.log get `[2016-05-30 09:52:32] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Newsletter' block's name: 'subscribe_0' [] []`

Comment: @xanka flush the `var/cache` and `var/generation` folders

Comment: my template in admin.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism : How can I call this in static block?? 
I've tried following {{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}  but not working

Comment: @KaushalSuthar well that should work like that. Did you flush cache and compiled files ?

Comment: Oh yes @RaphaelatDigitalPianism it worked, I was so excited and forgot to flush cache :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe')
          ->setTemplate('Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml')
          ->toHtml();
```